# concatenating tables in qlikview

Tags: qlikview

I have two qvw files with similar data and same columns (e.g. data2016.qvw with 1000 rows and 20 columns and data2017.qvw with 2000 rows and 20 columns). How can I join then in one unique matrix (i.e. obtaining database with 3000 rows and 20 columns)?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

By default, QlikView behaviour is to consider two separate LOAD procedures with exactly the same number of columns and all columns with the same name as to be placed under the same table.

So if you do LOAD .. FROM File1.csv and then LOAD ... from File2.csv, and these files share the same structure, all of the data will be placed in the same table.

Your issue could be the fact that your data is a qvw file already. I would suggest exporting the data to two separate qvd files and then do two LOAD commands on a new qvw.

If your your only datasource is the qvw, you can try to extract the data by using the BINARY command on a new qvw file.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [CONCATENATE](http://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/12.1/Subsystems/Client/Content/Scripting/ScriptPrefixes/concatenate.htm) function

Example 1:

```
LOAD * From file2.csv;
Concatenate SELECT * From table3;
```

Example 2:

```
tab1:
LOAD * From file1.csv;
tab2:
LOAD * From file2.csv;
.. .. ..
Concatenate (tab1) LOAD * From file3.csv;
```